# Invalid date on newDate(isoDate)?

Tags: javascript, android, android-2.3-gingerbread

How do I convert an ISO Date string to a Date object in Android 2.3?

I'm using the code below:

```
new Date('2013-08-25T06:30:00.000')
```

It's working on both iOS and other Android versions except for Android 2.3. When I execute the command above in Android 2.3, I am receiving an Invalid Date error message. It also important for me to keep the time part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Date class in java has following constructor and you can use one of them to create a `Date` object.

```
Date()
```

Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.

```
Date(int year, int month, int date)
```

Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).

```
Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min)
```

Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min).

```
Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec)
```

Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec).

```
Date(long date)
```

Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

```
Date(String s)
```

Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s).

for details look [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/apidocs/java.util.Date.html)